# Create a Gradient from an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I get about creating a gradient from an image so that I can use it as the background for that image? Kind of a blurring effect as the background?

My html markup:

```
<div class="bck">
    <img class="thumb" src="20161204.jpg" />
</div>
```

Styling applied:

```
.bck {
        height:500px;
        width: 500px;
        background-color: #9d9e88;  //grey
    }
    .thumb {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        left: 30%;
        position: relative;
        top: 30%;
    }
```

which gives me

[image]

I want to **fill the background / create a gradient** by the colours used in this image.

Can this be done purely by css (*preferred*) ? Nevertheless, I am open to any JS library

Comment: I don't think that something like this can be done using css...

Comment: okay. I am open to any JS solutions as well.

Comment: I know this is an old question, just wanted to point that grade.js does exactly this: https://github.com/benhowdle89/grade

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved in 2 ways.

1. Using **CSS**:

This is a very simple trick in which you can use the same image for the outer `<div>` and blur it out like this

```
.image_blur {
    -webkit-filter: blur(50px);
    -moz-filter: blur(50px);
    -o-filter: blur(50px);
    -ms-filter: blur(50px);
    filter: blur(50px);
}
```

Here is a [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZY5hn/177/) which gives the feel of a gradient.

2. using **Javascript**:

You can use canvas based StackBlur to blur the image that you can then use as your background-img (in the outer div) which will again give a feel of a gradient. Here is a working [example](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html).

Hope this helps.